# need help with wordpress add_action init to recognise is_single

Tags: php, wordpress

I have,

```
function my_function_init(){
    global $post;
    if(is_single()) {
        echo $post->ID;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_function_init');
```

this doesn't work for me, it doesn't recognize if its a post even if its a post (is_single() = checks if its a post), i have this in the plugin i am writing for wordpress, please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it
the solution is

```
add_action('get_header', 'my_function_init');
```

thats the fix :)